# Singer module in python - how do I get it running?

Tags: python-3.x

I am really sorry for this question but I am super confused around how to get Singer running on my Mac. I've installed it with `pip3 install singer-python`, but doing `import singer` I end up with an error that the module doesn't exist. Can you help?

Comment: Are you running it with `python` or `python3`? Since you did `pip3 install` you are using `python3` to run it right?

Comment: I was using a python3 jupyter notebook. Weirdly, having just read your comment, I lauched a python2 notebook and it works. I don't claim to understand, but I'll take it :) - Thanks!!

Comment: Either you did `pip install` instead of `pip3` or somewhere you are in a virtual environment. I would recommend getting it to work with Python3 since soon Python2 wont be supported.